# how to reset internal hard disk drive access permissions on windows 7

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, administrator, uac, access-control

I restricted the access permissions of F drive on my hard disk after that my os is changed without removing the permissions thats why i am not able to access that drive, can any one help me ??

Comment: `TAKEOWN /F F:\ /R /A /D Y` and  `ICACLS "F:\" /reset /T`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it by following this procedure,
Right click on F Drive ->properties->security->Select Group or user name->click edit and then type the object name to select 'Everyone' ->Click OK and you'll be returned to the Permissions dialog. Click on "Everyone", and then click on the "Full Control" check box.
->Click on OK.

After that open the Command prompt by right click and select Run as administrator, and type

C:\Windows\system32>cd /d f:\dell
c:\dell>
c:\dell>takeown /F * /R
c:\dell>icacls * /grant:r everyone:f /t